# How to stop Python Websocket client "ws.run_forever"

Tags: python, websocket

I'm starting my Python Websocket using "ws.run_forever", another [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete) stated that I should use "run_until_complete()" but these functions only seem available to Python asyncio.

How can I stop a websocket client? Or how to start it withouth running forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's also a `close` method on `WebSocketApp` which sets `keep_running` to False and also closes the socket

Answer (score 20):

In python websockets, you can use "ws.keep_running = False" to stop the "forever running" websocket.

This may be a little unintuitive and you may choose another library which may work better overall.

The code below was working for me (using ws.keep_running = False).

```
class testingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
    def run(self):
        print str(self.threadID) + " Starting thread"
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost/ws", on_error = self.on_error, on_close = self.on_close, on_message=self.on_message,on_open=self.on_open)
        self.ws.keep_running = True 
        self.wst = threading.Thread(target=self.ws.run_forever)
        self.wst.daemon = True
        self.wst.start()
        running = True;
        testNr = 0;
        time.sleep(0.1)
        while running:          
            testNr = testNr+1;
            time.sleep(1.0)
            self.ws.send(str(self.threadID)+" Test: "+str(testNr)+")
        self.ws.keep_running = False;
        print str(self.threadID) + " Exiting thread"
```

Comment: Are there any recommendations for alternative Python Websocket libraries?

Comment: I think this isn't really a valid comment to this post, you may be better off creating an "question" yourself or use Google to find other recommendations. Though the real question is why?

Comment: I asked this question because you specifically stated that the library in the question was unintuitive, which suggests the existence of better alternatives.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point, though it was quite some time ago and I haven't quite dug deeper into Python. I've been using NodeJS more and more lately, but that can be completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Paul I used your solution but added a `close_connection` function that sets `self.ws.keep_running = False` and `self.running = False`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to use an asynchronous dispatcher like rel. It will handle keyboard interrupt and then you can pass in a custom callback function while registering for keyboard interrupt event