# how to start a websocket file from another function

Tags: python, websocket

I have a WebSocket connection to a third party service in a `websocket_service.py` like below

```
import websocket


def on_message(ws, msg):
    print("Message Arrived:" + msg)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("Connection Closed")


def on_open(ws):
    print("Sending json")
    data = '{"request":{"streaming_type":"quote", "data":data, "request_type":"subscribe", "response_format":"json"}}'
    ws.send(data)
    ws.send("\n")

headers = {'x-session-token': '12a8a2b304142425a1e52f109ff02cb2'}

websocket.enableTrace(True)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://stream.stocknote.com", on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error,
                            on_close=on_close, header=headers)

ws.run_forever()
```

If I run `python websocket_service.py` it starts. But what I want is to start it from another method which is in another file using discord

> main.py

```
import discord


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'we have logged in as {client.user}')
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author==client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$start_websocket'):
        #how can I start the websocket connection here???
        await message.channel.send('websocket started')



client.run(TOKEN_ENV)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is putting below code into a function.

```
headers = {'x-session-token': '12a8a2b304142425a1e52f109ff02cb2'}
websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://stream.stocknote.com", on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close, header=headers)
ws.run_forever()
```

Then on the main file, put this statement at top "from websocket_service import the-funct-name". Now you can call the funct anywhere within the main file to start the socket.

Comment: This could work. But in this case, how can we close the WebSocket later from main.py?

Comment: The method you suggested wont work. getting handshake error.

Comment: I found a relevant answer to your new question in here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995640/how-to-stop-python-websocket-client-ws-run-forever)
I think you should construct the websocket file as a class for better use?